# ASP.NET Core + React + Node.js on Raspberry Pi proxying requests does not work

Tags: c#, reactjs, node.js, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

I attempted to create a relatively simple website using the base-template provided in Visual Studio with React already integrated (and, as I understand, Node.js). However, I encountered an issue with redirecting requests from Node.js handlers to ASP.NET Core. While the project runs smoothly on my computer, I encountered an error when attempting the same on my Raspberry Pi:

> [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request 192.168.0.101:44463/login to http://192.168.0.101:5124/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

In browser:

[Error in browser debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrAVM.png)

Regarding IP addresses:

- Connected from computer 192.168.0.100;
- ASP.NET Core and reaction are located at 192.168.101;
- ASP.NET Core port 5124, react port 44463

`setupProxy.js` code:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? http://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT} :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5015';

const context = [
    "/login",
    "/registration",
    "/tokenvalidation",
    "/statistic",
];

module.exports = function (app) {
    const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
        proxyTimeout: 10000,
        target: target,
        secure: false,
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    });

    app.use(appProxy);
};
```

`Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using CheckersOnlineSPA.ClientApp;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CheckersOnlineSPA.Data;
using CheckersOnlineSPA.Services.OnlineClientsWatcher;
using CheckersOnlineSPA.Services.Browser;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets;
using CheckersOnlineSPA.Services.Games;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://192.168.0.101:5124");

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<BrowserController>();
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<OnlineClientsWatcher>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GamesController>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = Auth.AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = Auth.AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = Auth.AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };
    });

string conn = "Server=192.168.0.101;Database=checkers;Uid=dimon;Pwd=qwerty123123;";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySql(conn, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(conn)));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<GameMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<BrowserMiddleware>();
//app.UseMiddleware<ClientsCounterMiddleware>();

app.MapPost("/login", Auth.LoginHandler);
app.MapPost("/registration", Auth.RegistrationHandle);
app.MapPost("/tokenvalidation", Auth.TokenValidationHandler);
app.MapPost("/statistic", ClientsActivity.GetClientsActivityHandler );

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Entire project on github:

[Source code on github](https://github.com/asmcodersource/CheckersOnline)

Comment: Hi ASMcoder, could you kindly check the answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

When VS2022 starts the project in the dev environment, the React project will enable port `44463`, and your ASP.NET Core uses port `5124`.

However, in the published files, the React project will be compiled into static resource files and processed by app.UseStaticFiles();,

#### so only one port is enabled in your Raspberry Pi.

So you need to change below code:

```
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `http://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5015';
```

Just make sure that the published front-end and back-end ports are consistent.